# pandas unstack a dataframe and stack series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe and I want to do some operations for some rows

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

For example, I want to take out row 5, 8, 10:

```
series_5 = df.iloc[5,:]
series_8 = df.iloc[8,:]
series_10 = df.iloc[10,:]
```

Each of them would be a series indexed by columns of df. its name would be the index of df, e.g.:

```
>>> series_5
A    22
B    14
C     3
D    22
Name: 5, dtype: int64
```

After some operation on each of these three series, I want to convert them back to a dataframe that in the same format (and index) as df, i.e.

```
df_new:

     A   B   C   D
5    56  72  73  92
8    16  13  42  69
10   85  16  68  76
```

I am now stuck at creating this new dataframe after updating values of series 5, 8, 10 (for demonstration, you can assume the values are the same as before). And I also want to ask about how to do the next step: updating df with df_new for those three rows. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a dataframe from a collection of series:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame([series_5, series_8, series_10])
```

Comment: thanks... didnt expect the solution to be this simple... i spent a lot of time thinking how to convert series names into index for df_new